# How to stop reusing uitableviewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, lazy-loading

Hi in my app i have to load images to `UITableViewCell` .which are coming from the server.so the problem is  when ever i scroll the tableview images are loading every time and its loading lazy so i tried to stop reusing cells but its not working ,How to stop reusing the cells in `UITableView`. 
my code is

```
     -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
RestaurantCustomCell *cell =(RestaurantCustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSArray *topLevelObjects ;
topLevelObjects= [[NSArray alloc]init];
if(cell==nil)
{
        topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RestaurantCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (RestaurantCustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
 NSDictionary *dict=[restauarantsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *imgStr=[dict valueForKey:@"Img"];
[self processImageDataWithURLString:imgStr andBlock:^(NSData *imageData) {
    if (self.view.window)
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        if(img!=nil)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(100, 100));
            [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
            UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            cell.restaurantImg.image=newImage;
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
    }
}];

cell.nameLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Restaurants"];
cell.typeLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Rest_Cuisine"];
cell.timingsLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Rest_Timings"];
cell.categoryLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Rest_Category"];
cell.addressLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Address"];

return cell;
 }
```

Comment: I would really suggest you look to another solution, nor reusing your cell is bad for memory usage and could cause your app to crash.

Comment: Previously i tried with custom cell only. even there i have faced the same problem

Comment: No that is very bad idea.

Comment: @CRDave: what is bad idea

Comment: Stop reusing cell is a bad idea, you will have bad scrolling effect for sure because stack an object like a cell in memory is big enough to slow down your thread, even some milliseconds, and you will see it when you scroll, it will have micro freezing screen effect...

Comment: ok is there any  way to stop loading images every time

Answer (score 0):

You can not doing this in default **table view cell**. If you want to create this kind of things then you need to create custom **tableview** cell anbd do it what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom cell like that:

**RestaurantCustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RestaurantCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *typeLbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timingsLbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *restauranImg;


@end
```

**RestaurantCustomCell.m**

```
#import "RestaurantCustomCell.h"

@implementation RestaurantCustomCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)prepareForReuse{
    self.nameLbl.text = @"";
    self.typeLbl.text = @"";
    self.timingsLbl.text = @"";
    self.categoryLbl.text = @"";
    self.addressLbl.text = @"";
}

@end
```

after in IB you add a new `UITableViewCell` at your `UITableView` and the class of it with you new custom cell set the Identify ID like "RestaurantCustomCell" add your labels and imageView to your custom cell and connect the Outlet, then you modify you   `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like that:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"RestaurantCustomCell";
RestaurantCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 NSDictionary *dict=[restauarantsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *imgStr=[dict valueForKey:@"Img"];
[self processImageDataWithURLString:imgStr andBlock:^(NSData *imageData) {
    if (self.view.window)
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        if(img!=nil)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(100, 100));
            [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
            UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            cell.restaurantImg.image=newImage;
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
    }
}];

cell.nameLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Restaurants"];
cell.typeLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Rest_Cuisine"];
cell.timingsLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Rest_Timings"];
cell.categoryLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Rest_Category"];
cell.addressLbl.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Address"];

return cell;
```

Comment: yeah i did the same thing

Comment: you put the data of the image in an NSArray (you have you image save in local or you download it from a server?)